# How to play multiple videos in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to play a video in a res of 720p (1280x720) with an autoplay and a loop whenever the video ends replace by another video in array.

the first video works fine, but it didn't autoplay, and after it end. it does not continue to play another video.

here's my code :

```
            <div class="content-left">
                <video controls id="myVideo" width="1280" height="720" autoplay></video>
                    <script>
                    var videoSource = new Array();
                    videoSource[0]='videos/bluevideo.mp4';
                    videoSource[1]='videos/redvideo.mp4';
                    videoSource[2]='videos/yellowvideo.mp4';
                    var videoCount = videoSource.length;

                    document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource[0]); 

                    function videoPlay(videoNum)
                        {
                    document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource[videoNum]);
                    document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
                    document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
                        }
                        document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
                        function myHandler() {
                        i++;
                        if(i == (videoCount-1)){
                        i = 0;
                        videoPlay(i);
                        }
                        else{
                        videoPlay(i);
                        }

                            }

                    </script>

            </div>
```

where did I do wrong? can anyone help me?thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable `i` which you increment in `myHandler`. However, it isn't declared anywhere. You should declare it outside the code of the event handler, and set the value to the first index:

```
var videoSource = new Array();
videoSource[0] = 'videos/bluevideo.mp4';
videoSource[1] = 'videos/redvideo.mp4';
videoSource[2] = 'videos/yellowvideo.mp4';
var videoCount = videoSource.length;
var i = 0;
document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", videoSource[0]);

function videoPlay(videoNum) {
    document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", videoSource[videoNum]);
    document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
    document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);

function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if (i == videoCount) {
        i = 0;
        videoPlay(i);
    } else {
        videoPlay(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you. but now it doesn't play the third video can u explain why, I'm beginner at coding.

Comment: I've updated the code. Since you increment `i` prior to evaluating `if(i == (videoCount-1))` the value of `i` would be reset to zero after the second video is played.

Comment: it works thankyou Daekard. very kind of you. but i wonder why my video does not autoplay. i have inserted the "autoplay" code recently but it seems not work.

Comment: Many browsers have in recent years adopted a policy of blocking autoplay unless the video is muted or the user expressly plays the video. There are a number of reasons given [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). You can try adding the `muted` attribute to the `video` tag, however, the video will play without sound.